# Return value of Promise's resolve/reject functions

Tags: javascript, promise, return-value

Consider this situation.

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var x = resolve(2);
});
```

What value will `x` be? 
I tried to print it and it showed me `undefined`. It is intuitive, but is it always so? Is it in docs?

Second question

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(2);
    return 5;
});
```

What should we return from the function that we put into a promise? Is this value ignored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value of the promise constructor [is ignored](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise-executor).

The `resolve` function also [returns undefined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise-resolve-functions).

This was first specified in the promise constructor spec and later in the ES2015 (ES6) [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-newpromisecapability).

Comment: @MichałKownacki I've added citations, namely check the note in http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise-executor

Comment: Yeah but I'm using node.js with Bluebird, it uses Promises/A+ standard.

Comment: @MichałKownacki not only does bluebird behave this way, in 3.0 we warn against it: http://imgur.com/a/t3xng