# Return value from a Promise constructor

Tags: javascript, promise

Consider two examples below...

#### TEST 1

```
function test1() {
    return new Promise(function () {
        return 123;
    });
}

test1()
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("DATA:", data);
        return 456;
    })
    .then(function (value) {
        console.log("VALUE:", value);
    });
```

It outputs nothing.

#### TEST 2

```
function test2() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(123);
    });
}

test2()
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("DATA:", data);
        return 456;
    })
    .then(function (value) {
        console.log("VALUE:", value);
    });
```

It outputs:

```
DATA: 123
VALUE: 456
```

What are the drawbacks or [spec](https://promisesaplus.com/) contradictions for a promise constructor not to simply resolve a returned value in TEST 1?

Why does it have to be a different result than in TEST 2?

I'm trying to understand how a constructed promise object is different from a then-able object as per the [promise spec](https://promisesaplus.com/).

Comment: which `Promise` library is this?

Comment: @jamiec es6 promise.

Comment: @Jamiec ES6 Promise within NodeJS 4.1.1

Comment: ok, I thought so but wasnt 100%

Comment: [The returned value is to be ignored per the spec](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31651610/1048572) (as it obviously has, to be able to wait for asynchronous `resolve` calls). Check out [the design of the constructor pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28687566/1048572). If you are looking for the differences between thenables and promises, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29435262/1048572).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function passed to `Promise` isn't a callback for `onFulfilled` or `onRejected`. MDN calls it the `executor`. Think of it as the async context that the promise is attempting to capture. Returning from an async method doesn't work (or make sense), hence you have to call `resolve` or `reject`. For example

```
var returnVal = new Promise(function() {
     return setTimeout(function() {
         return 27;
     });
});
```

... does not work as intended. If you were to return a value from the `executor` before your async calls finished, the promise couldn't be re-resolved.

Also, it could be ambigous with the implicit `return undefined;` at the end of the function. Consider these executors that function the same way.

```
// A
function a() { return undefined; }

// B
function b() { }
```

What would tell the `Promise` constructor that you really wanted to resolve with `undefined`?

```
a() === b(); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that there is a shorthand for returning a resolved promise, [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(123);
});
```

simply becomes

```
return Promise.resolve(123);
```

Comment: The result is the same, but what's happening underneath isn't. The second one will always perform better. And depending on the promise implementation, the second one can perform much better.

Comment: Absolutely. The flow is similar (although it probably depends on implementation, I've taken a look in bluebird) but it skips some unnecessary steps.