# Clarification of node.js + promises snippet

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, promise, es6-promise

The accepted answer for [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) has this example:

```
function getUserDataAsync(userId){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
         getUserData(userId,resolve,reject);
    });
}
```

Questions:

1. Shouldn't the body of `Promise` return something, not just call `getUserData` (at least in practical code, not as promise demonstration exercise)?
2. Is this particular `Promise` also a closure? It seems like it closes over `userId`, as `getUserDataAsync` creates and returns a new `Promise` instance using `userId`, but I want to be sure.

Comment: 1. No. [The return value is ignored by the `Promise` constructor anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31651610/1048572). 2. Yes, the function expression that is passed to the constructor forms a closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't the body of Promise return something, not just call `getUserData` (at least in practical code, not as promise demonstration exercise)?

No, it doesn't have to. In fact, returning a value from the `Promise` constructor will have no effect. **Only `resolve` and `reject` functions can fulfill a `Promise`.**

> Is this particular `Promise` also a closure? It seems like it closes over `userId`, as `getUserDataAsync` creates and returns a new `Promise` instance using `userId`, but I want to be sure.

Yes, the function passed to the `Promise` constructor closes over `userId`.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it shouldn't return something, because there is nothing to return *at that point in time*, hence the reason you are using a promise.
2. Yes.