# Should you return something after resolving or rejecting in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Lets say I have a Promise like the following:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  // Some random conditional
  if (today === 'Friday') {
    console.log("I'm resolving this thing here");
    resolve('taco');
    // Should I have a return true or false here?
  }

  console.log("Code made it past the first resolve");

  // Do some other code here, like connect to a database or API or something.
  connectToDatabase(function(result){
    // result was 'hamburger'
    resolve(result);
  });

}).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

In this example, I get the following output:

```
I'm resolving this thing here
Code made it past the first resolve
taco
```

So, after I do a `resolve`, the Promise code continues to execute. In my above example, I unnecessarily connect to some database or endpoint or something. Obviously the send `resolve` is ignored, which is just fine. But connecting to databases and APIs is expensive from a service cost standpoint, especially if it costs you money every time you make a request like an AWS service or something.

So my question is, should I be putting in a `return true;` or something in after that first `resolve`?

Similarly with `reject`, should I put in a `return false` or (true??) after a `reject`?

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  someAsyncFunction((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
      // Should I have a return true or false here or something?
    }

    // Do something here, like connect to a database or fetch a value from some API endpoint or something.

    resolve(result);
  });
});
```

If I don't want the code to be executed after that `reject` I should return, correct?

When I look through all sorts of ES6 documentation, I can't find any places where they make this clear... Lots of Promise examples are usually really simplified.

If I do return something on these, what should I return? `true`? `false`? or `return resolve('taco');`?

Comment: If you need to do another promise handle it in .then for resolve or .catch for reject.

Comment: `Should I be putting in a return true; or something in after that first resolve?` not necessarily - it could be perfectly valid to continue with some other code after you resolve (or reject) - as long as you understand that any further resolves/rejects are ignored, there's no reason to "return" at that point

Comment: return Promise.reject(new Error(err)); its good to return reject

Comment: @UmakantMane. You *must* just use `reject` to settle the `Promise`. Your suggestion would actually leave the `Promise` to be unsettled potentially upholding the entire promise chain.

Comment: A Promise executor a.k.a `(resolve, reject) => ... ` function is a point of "point of no return" once it's invoked. Everything happening afterwards shall remain within executor's context. In your question you can use as many `resolve`s or `reject`s as you want but your algo should only invoke them either once or never.

Comment: @zeroflagL I'm not trying to resolve more than once. I'm trying to `resolve` a different value depending on certain conditions. For example, if condition === true, resolve something, otherwise do some stuff (like fetch a value from an API or something) and then resolve a different value. Was I not clear on that?

Comment: @JaromandaX But what if the code after the `reject` or `resolve` is something I don't want to execute? What if it involves connecting to API endpoints or fetching things from a database. Those kind of things are expensive from a processing standpoint and from a service cost standpoint. In that case, I should return after the `resolve` or `reject` right? I must have not been clear in my question since people really aren't understanding me it seems.

Comment: Also have a look at [Return value of Promise's resolve/reject functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31651610/1048572)

Comment: "*If I don't want the code to be executed after that reject I should `return`*" - YES. Or you just use an `else` with your `if`. "*should I put in a return false or true?*" - the value is ignored anyway, so don't return anything and just put a `return;`. Or put the keyword before the reject: `return reject(…)`.

Comment: Regarding the "*Do something here*" in your second snippet - you shouldn't be doing that. Just `resolve(result)` and don't do anything else. You are promisifying `someAsyncFunction`, everything what happens after that should go in a `then` callback. If you need to "*connect to a database or fetch a value from some API endpoint or something*", create an extra promise for that.

Comment: Regarding your first example, see also [Idiomatically handling pre-conditions with ES6 Promises](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35856041/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I understand, but what if only sometimes I need to run `someAsyncFunction`? For example, if `today==='Friday'`, then `resolve(a)` otherwise, run `someAsyncFunction` and resolve a different value. Why should I split this up into multiple Promises if that extra bit of code is only executed sometimes? Also thank you for your responses. Very helpful. Feel free to user a proper answer below for some credit.

Comment: I just think that `if (today == 'Friday') return Promise.resolve(a); /*else*/ return new Promise(…)` is easier to read, and you get the necessary early return for free.

Comment: Or was this directed at the comment "*regarding the Do something here*"? Then, the argument is basically that the `someAsyncFunction` callback is unsafe (errors thrown won't be caught) and you should promisify on the lowest level possible. Combining promises is more simple and safe (less errorprone) than combining multiple callbacks.

Answer (score -3):

basic level understanding of how promises works and when to use resolve, reject

```
   function d() {
     console.log("D started");
     return Promise.reject(new Error("Aborted from D function"));

   //return Promise.resolve("Done with D");
 }

function c() {
console.log("C Started");
//return Promise.reject(new Error("Aborted from C function"));
//return Promise.resolve("Done with C");
return d().then(result => {
       return Promise.resolve(result);  
}).catch(err => {
       return Promise.reject(new Error(err));
});
}

function b() {
  console.log("B Started");
  //return Promise.reject(new Error("Aborted from B function"));
 return Promise.resolve("Done With B");
   }

    function a() {
    console.log("A started");
    return b().then(function(resultb){
        console.log("B result:"+resultb);
        return c();
 }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("Error:"+err)
}).then(function(resultc){
       console.log("C result:"+resultc)
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Error:"+err);  
  });
   }

  a();
```