# Recursive promise not continuing on then block when called

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise

I have a recursive promise which will poll something 5 time before resolving.

```
let retries = 0

function poll(i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (retries === 5) throw new Error('done')

        if (i === 0) return resolve('foo')
        else retries++

        console.log(i - 1)

        return poll(i - 1)
    })
}
```

But if i call the function like so, i cannot access the resolved data.

```
poll(4)
    .then(data => console.log('result?', data))
    .catch(err => console.log('caught err', err))
```

The only way to access the data from the resolve is to attach a then block on the end of the 'return new Promise' chain like so:

```
function poll(i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (retries === 5) throw new Error('done')

        if (i === 0) return resolve('foo')
        else retries++

        console.log(i - 1)

        return poll(i - 1)
    }).then(data => console.log('result?', data))
}
```

However, i did manage to get access to the data when calling the poll function by doing the following:

```
function poll(i) {
    if (retries === 5) throw new Error('done')

    if (i === 0) return Promise.resolve('foo')
    else retries++

    console.log(i - 1)

    return poll(i - 1)
}
```

My question is, why did the first snippet of code not work, but the last snippet did?

From what i understand about Promises, Promise.resolve() and resolve() are the same thing?

Comment: You cannot `return` anything from the `new Promise` executor callback. No, `resolve` inside a promise constructor is a very different thing.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651610/return-value-of-promises-resolve-reject-functions

Comment: Notice that you should `return Promise.reject(…)` instead of `throw`ing in your second snippet. Also, why are you using promises here at all when you're not doing anything asynchronous?